# Measuring DRY-ness of Asp.Net code using Static Analysis

Tags: asp.net, dry, static-analysis

Are there static analysis tools for Asp.Net that measure the DRY-ness ("Don't Repeat Yourself") of code?

I would like to get a report of where code is being duplicated within a Asp.Net project.

Comment: The search terms i was looking for is clone detection and code duplicate detection. For the C# part of Asp.Net, the question is asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204177/what-tool-to-find-code-duplicates-in-c-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) tool can detect duplicated code across VB.net and C# code, which form a substantial part of an ASP.net application.  CloneDR handles detection across very large systems.

We can build clone detectors (using the same foundations) trivially for HTML; we have all the pieces but literally haven't assembled them.

We don't have something specically for ASP.net files with interwoven ASP code (it looks like HTML but isnt quite) with intermixed .net code; we could build such without much effort.  You can see something like this in our CloneDR for JavaScript, which will process HTML pages containing javascript elements.